# Hex Dump Utility C++ Displaying Hex and Ascii

Tags: c++, hex, ascii, dump, utility

Alright so I call read file to fill up the slop trough but it only works with .txt or .bin files and crashes when I open anything else, such as .doc files with 
error code 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0xFFFFFFFF.

Also is this even the correct way to go about displaying to screen the hex and ascii dumps of a file?

```
//The slop_trough I dump all the hex and ascii slop into
unsigned char slop_trough [MAX] = {0} ;

void ReadFile (string filename, unsigned char slop_trough [])
{
ifstream open_bin;
open_bin.open(  filename, ios::in | ios::binary  ) ;
if ( open_bin.is_open() )
{
    open_bin.read ( reinterpret_cast <char *> (slop_trough),
        sizeof(slop_trough) * MAX ) ;

    open_bin.close();
}
else
    cout << "File not opened!" << endl;

}

void HexDump (unsigned char slop_trough [])
{
for ( int j = 0; j < MAX - 1; ++j)
{
   cout << hex << slop_trough[j] ;
}
}

void AsciiDump(unsigned char slop_trough [])
{
for ( int p = 0; p < MAX - 1; ++p)
{
   cout << slop_trough[p];
}
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(slop_trough) * MAX` This will read `sizeof(unsigned char*) * MAX` characters, which will generally be anywhere from 4 to 8 times the actual size of your buffer.

Comment: What if the file is shorter than `MAX` bytes? Why are you multiplying the size of the array by `MAX`?

Comment: @user657267 `slop_trough` is an array, not a pointer. So it will actually read `MAX * MAX` bytes. Arrays don't decay to pointers when used in `sizeof`.

Comment: @Barmar `slop_trough` in the function is a pointer to `unsigned char`, don't let the `[]` syntax fool you.

Comment: Oops, you're right, didn't notice that it was a function argument as well as a global variable. Using the same variable name is another bad practice.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @user657267! Looks like I was going past my array, I just cut out the * MAX thing and everything seems to be working now. I should get garbage ascii characters for inputting a .doc file right?

Comment: You still need to get the actual length of the file and limit everything to that number of bytes.

Comment: @MrPickles7 You should be leaving `MAX` and getting rid of the `sizeof` part.

Comment: How I got rid of sizeof part seems to have fixed all my problems,    open_bin.read ( reinterpret_cast <char *> (slop_trough),
   * &MAX  ) ;

Comment: `* &MAX` why not just `MAX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
streamsize ReadFile (const string &filename, unsigned char *slop, int max_slop)
{
    ifstream open_bin;

    open_bin.open( filename, ios::in | ios::binary  ) ;
    if ( !open_bin.is_open() )
    {
        cout << "File not opened! " << filename << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    if( !open_bin.read ( reinterpret_cast<char*>(slop), max_slop ) )
    {
        cout << "File not read! " << filename << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return open_bin.gcount();
}

void HexDump (unsigned char *slop, streamsize slop_len)
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < slop_len; ++j)
    {
        cout << noshowbase << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << slop[j] << ansi::reset();
        cout.put(' ');
    }
    cout << dec << setw(0) << setfill(' ');
}

void AsciiDump(unsigned char *slop, streamsize slop_len)
{
    for ( int p = 0; p < slop_len; ++p)
    {
       if ( (slop[p] > 0x20) && (slop[p] < 0x7F) && (slop[p] != 0x0A) && (slop[p] != 0x0D) )
           cout << slop[p];
       else
           cout << '.';
    }
    cout << ansi::reset();
}
```

```
//The slop_trough I read the file data into
unsigned char slop_trough [MAX] = {0} ;

streamsize slop_len = ReadFile ( "filename", slop_trough, MAX );
unsigned char *slop = slop_trough;

while ( slop_len >= 16 )
{
    HexDump ( slop, 16 );
    cout << "| "; 
    AsciiDump( slop, 16 );
    cout << endl;

    slop += 16;
    slop_len -= 16;
}

if ( slop_len > 0 )
{
    HexDump ( slop, slop_len );
    cout << left << setw(48 - (slop_len * 3)) << setfill(' ') << "| ";
    AsciiDump( slop, slop_len );
}
```

Have a look at this example for a more robust hex viewer implementation:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NwTbqMoL/

Comment: Wow thanks Remy! I am having problems getting this to read some binary files, it keeps not finding them and slop_ptr is undefined I don't really know what it does so I commented it out.

Comment: `slop_ptr` should be `slop` instead. I have corrected it. As for opening files, it is your responsibility to make sure you are providing a correct `filename` to `ReadFile()`.

Comment: Nice. I'm just getting a string from the user and passing it into ReadFile() without quotation marks! Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate it, one day I'll be able to give back to SO